# finding element in the active slide of Bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm trying to do something to a div that is inside a Bootstrap 3 carousel. How do I find that div, though?

```
 $('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    var carouselData = $(this).data('bs.carousel');
              var currentIndex = carouselData.getItemIndex(carouselData.$element.find('.item.active'));

    //now I know the current item, but how do I change the .description div
    //inside that item?


    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `carouselData.getItemIndex`, why not just manipulate that element directly?

```
carouselData.$element.find('.item.active .description').text("New content here");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution was almost complete. For anyone searching for a solution and landing here:

```
$('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
  // mind the e parameter I added               ^ here
  var carouselData = $(this).data('bs.carousel');
  var currentIndex = carouselData.getItemIndex($(e.relatedTarget));

  // but that is unnecessary because the current slide is in e.relatedTarget
  var currentItem = $(e.relatedTarget);
  // currentItem is the current slide's div, use it
});
```